# Apportable doesn't show custom UIScroll on android and some other issues

Tags: apportable

I have ported my ios game to android using indie version. It has following issues:

1. Custom scroll implemented through code doesn't show up
2. Touches on ccmenu works on and off i.e i have to restart the game again and again sometimes they work sometimes they don't.
3. Nib files have the same issue mentioned in step two. Works on and off have to restart again and again.
4. Game icon is not appearing
5. Sometimes game stucks randomly and crashes.

Update:

Note: UIScroll works where we have used them in tableView and doesn't work where we have only used UIscroll.

Comment: Not sure it's your issue, but one of the fixes in today's upcoming release is proper touch handling in UIScrollView.

Comment: Thanks @PaulBeusterien, i guess i have that update and it is still not working :(

Comment: Please provide a test case.

Comment: Hi Tashfeen, could you give logs from running "apportable log" in both the case where it seems to work correctly and the case it doesn't work?

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16746512/logs%202.zip

contains logs,hprof,snapshots

Comment: @itfische i have taken logs in all scenerios and screenshots.   
dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16746512/logs%202.zip contains logs,hprof,snapshots PaulBeusterien run game multiple times and on every run it has different behaviour. i can also send the logs and snapshots i have also taken the dump. and there are lot of crashes due out of memory –

Comment: @PaulBeusterien any progess ? help would be appreciated :)

Comment: It may not be diagnosable without a smaller test case or source code. You could try to reproduce and narrow down by adding pieces of the scroll view to the Spin sample app. One additional idea from looking at the logs could be that you have WebView's embedded in ScrollView's which may cause issues on the Apportable platform